# mutiple statments with np.where

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there any way to apply multiple statements with np.where instead , for example I want to change 3 columns or more and add 2 arguments when condition is true.

```
    a           b           c          d
99.00        101.77       101.96      99.68
```

I want to change column b, c, d to different numbers if column a = 99, the reason I want to use numpy where is this is the fastest way to iterate rows I can found so far and I only know how to  change 1 column at a time.

my code :

```
np.where(df['a'] = '99', df['b'] = 101.775286, '0')
```

```
desire result :
if a = 99 change
b = 101.77, c = 101.96, d = 99.68, e = b + c, f = b + c + d
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't work because you don't have `==` as a condition...

Comment: `np.where(c,a,b)` creates a new frame or series constructed from elements of `a` or `b`.  You can assign that to (parts of) an existing frame.  But `a` and `b` have make sense by themselves.  `np.where` is NOT an iterator.  Practice with simpler cases first.

Comment: There are many SO about using `np.where` with pandas.  To be clear here I'd suggest a small example (not just one line), and iterative code.  That gives a clearer idea of your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of changing and/or creating multiple columns of dataframe.

First a basic frame (we prefer to use OP supplied examples):

```
In [4]: import pandas as pd
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2), 'b':(3,4)})
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

First use `np.where` 'plain':

```
In [7]: np.where(df['a']<2, df['b']+1, df['b']-1)
Out[7]: array([4, 3], dtype=int64)
```

It is `numpy` function, so returns a numpy array result, even if the arguments are Series or frames.  In effect it's using the `.values`.

But that array can be assigned to a (new) column of a dataframe - this or another:

```
In [8]: df['c'] = np.where(df['a']<2, df['b']+1, df['b']-1)
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   a  b  c
0  1  3  4
1  2  4  3
```

We can go on work with several columns (a frame), again getting an array (now 2d):

```
In [10]: np.where(df['a']<2, df[['b','c']]+100, df[['b','c']])
Out[10]:
array([[103,   4],
       [104,   3]], dtype=int64)
```

and assign that to 2 columns of the frame:

```
In [11]: df[['c','d']]=np.where(df['a']<2, df[['b','c']]+100, df[['b','c']])
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   a  b    c  d
0  1  3  103  4
1  2  4  104  3
```

While `np.where` is often used in `pandas` to replace row iterations, it is still a `python/numpy` function.  It is not an 'iterator'.  Python evaluates all 3 arguments first, and then passes them to the function.  It then selects values based on the condition.  In fancier cases it applies `broadcasting` rules.

In fact, I just realized I made an error.  I intended to add 100 to the values of one row, but instead added them to one column (both rows of 'c').  The ran because I had 2 rows, and 2 columns.  If instead I try to set 3 columns, I get a `numpy` broadcasting error:

```
In [13]: np.where(df['a']<2, df[['b','c','d']]+100, df['b'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 np.where(df['a']<2, df[['b','c','d']]+100, df['b'])

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3) (2,)
```

So I have change the Series arguments from being 1d (2,) to being dataframes, with a (2,1) `.values` shape:

```
In [14]: np.where(df[['a']]<2, df[['b','c','d']]+100, df[['b']])
Out[14]:
array([[103, 203, 104],
       [  4,   4,   4]], dtype=int64)
```

Now the array shape is (2,3), with 100 added to just one row.  That can be assigned to the frame (column order can be changed):

```
In [15]: df[['b','d','c']]=np.where(df[['a']]<2, df[['b','c','d']]+100, df[['b']]
    ...: )
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   a    b    c    d
0  1  103  104  203
1  2    4    4    4
```

In sum, `np.where` cannot be fully applied to a dataframe without some basic understanding of both `python` and `numpy`, especially when trying to set values for multiple columns.